# How to get all unique values from Firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following collection in Firestore:

Users (Collection)

```
Users (Collection)
-- user1 (Document)
-----name: "John"
-----age: 23

-- user2 (Document)
-----name: "Mary"
-----age: 25

-- user3 (Document)
-----name: "John"
-----age: 20
```

**Question**: How can I query Firestore so that I get all unique names in the collection?

**Desired result**: (John, Mary)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no specific API to retrieve unique values from Cloud Firestore. You will have to retrieve all relevant documents and determine the unique names in your own code.

Alternatively, consider adding a document with unique names and update that with every write. This is a quite common approach in NoSQL databases, but may take some getting used to if you're new to them.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can do it with javascript v8 (and maybe admin js sdk):

```js
export const getUniqueFieldValues = async (collection, fieldName) => {
  const uniqueValues = [];
  let lastDoc;

  // without any where on fieldName, firestore would return documents without the field
  const withWhere = collection.where(fieldName, "!=", null);
  const [doc] = (await withWhere.orderBy(fieldName).limit(1).get()).docs;
  lastDoc = doc;
  const fieldValue = doc.get(fieldName);
  uniqueValues.push(fieldValue);

  do {
    // we need a not-in because the doc after `lastDoc` likely has the same value
    const withWhere = collection.where( fieldName, "not-in", uniqueValues.slice(-1));
    // use a db cursor to skip over the documents we know have values we've seen
    const [doc] = (
      await withWhere.orderBy(fieldName).startAfter(lastDoc).limit(1).get()
    ).docs;
    if (!doc) return uniqueValues; // return if we can't find any more unique values
    lastDoc = doc;
    const fieldValue = doc.get(fieldName);
    uniqueValues.push(fieldValue);
    // keep going to find more unique values
  } while (true);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about counting the number of times each unique value of the name property occurs in the users collection, like this:

```
db.collection("users").select("name", "COUNT(name) as count").groupBy("name").get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data().name, doc.data().count);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
```

This would return:

```
John 2
Mary 1
```