# Cloud Firestore: Is it possible to query a collection between two dates?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of events and each event document has the fields 
`'start_date'` and `'end_date'`. I want to do a query like so

```
db.collection(events).where('start_date', '>=', start).where('end_date', '<=', end)
```

Is this a valid query or does it fall under Invalid: Range filters on different fields?

If it is not valid what is a valid workaround to query between two time ranges?

Also how would I tie in other range queries such as price?

```
db.collection(events).where('categories.theatre', '==', true).where('price', '>=', price).where('start_date', '>=', start).where('end_date', '>=', end)
```

---

**EDIT:** The second portion is different from [Workaround for “Range filters on different fields” limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027326/workaround-for-range-filters-on-different-fields-limitation). Also, doing separate queries and combining them together creates duplicate data which there is not an easy way to find distinct on [How to get all unique values from Firestore collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024410/how-to-get-all-unique-values-from-firestore-collection)

Comment: I think you are correct: Range Filters on different fields is invalid.  However, you can `orderBy` 'end_date' and just use `limit` and `startAfter` to paginate through.

Comment: Range Filter and `orderBy` are valid on the same query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Workaround for "Range filters on different fields" limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027326/workaround-for-range-filters-on-different-fields-limitation)

Comment: @stcho Are you able to get a solution for this?