# How to count unique property occurrences in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if it is at all possible with Firestore to count how many times a unique value occurs.

For example: You have 1000 documents containing some properties, including a date. Of those 1000 documents, only about 50 different dates occur (so some have the same date). I would like to be able to get a list of every occurring date along with the amount of times it occurs.

Extra context: The documents are bookings and the desired output is for displaying the amount of bookings per day on a chart (Chart.js)

I tried to do it locally (in Express.js):

```
const counts = {};

tmpArr.forEach(function (x) {counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1});

// Gets me something like this:
=> {"25/12": 6,"26/12": 3,"27/12": 7}
```

Which works like a charm, with the exception that I have to fetch all 1000 documents from Firestore every single time. This is a real pain in terms of app performance as well as Firebase cost.

So does anyone know if there's a way to get a similar output without fetching all documents, like using a very advanced query or aggregation queries or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this answer, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024410/how-to-get-all-unique-values-from-firestore-collection/74956439#74956439

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in API to get the (count of) unique values from Firestore. You will either have to read all documents as you do now, or (as is common in NoSQL databases) modify your data model to allow the use-case more efficiently.

In this case for example you could add an additional collection where you keep a document for each unique date (or other property) with that date as its document ID. You then update this secondary collection (sometimes called an index) on every relevant write. So this complicates your process to write bookings, but it makes reading the dates very simple - which is another common trade-off when using NoSQL databases.

Also see:

- [How to get all unique values from Firestore collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024410/how-to-get-all-unique-values-from-firestore-collection)